# __declspec(dllimport) in release mode and debug mode in QT

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, taglib

i want to use taglib in my QT project on windows, so i build taglib and zlib from source like below:

```
cmake CMakeLists.txt
cmake --build --config release
```

cmake command uses visual studio compiler, i build zlib and taglib from source with above command with no error, i added their include and lib path to QT project .pro file like below:

```
INCLUDEPATH+=F:\project\TAGLIB\taglib\taglib F:\project\TAGLIB\taglib\taglib\toolkit F:\project\TAGLIB\taglib F:\project\zlib-1.2.11\Release F:\project\zlib-1.2.11
LIBS+=-LF:\project\zlib-1.2.11\Release -lzlib
LIBS+= -LF:\project\TAGLIB\taglib\taglib\Release -ltag
LIBS+=-LF:\project\TAGLIB\taglib\taglib\Debug -ltag
LIBS+=-LF:\project\zlib-1.2.11\Debug -lzlibd
```

and in main.cpp i added:

```
#include<fileref.h>
#include<tag.h>
#include<QDebug>
```

and in main function:

```
TagLib::FileRef f("C:\\Users\\sub\\Downloads\\Mohsen Chavoshi - Sharhe Alef.mp3");
TagLib::String artist = f.tag()->artist();
```

when i run my application in debug mode,it doesn't run and give me below errors:

```
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl TagLib::String::~String(void)" (__imp_??1String@TagLib@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function main
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: char const * __cdecl TagLib::String::toCString(bool)const " (__imp_?toCString@String@TagLib@@QEBAPEBD_N@Z) referenced in function main
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl TagLib::FileName::FileName(char const *)" (__imp_??0FileName@TagLib@@QEAA@PEBD@Z) referenced in function main
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl TagLib::FileRef::FileRef(class TagLib::FileName,bool,enum TagLib::AudioProperties::ReadStyle)" (__imp_??0FileRef@TagLib@@QEAA@VFileName@1@_NW4ReadStyle@AudioProperties@1@@Z) referenced in function main
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl TagLib::FileRef::~FileRef(void)" (__imp_??1FileRef@TagLib@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function main
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class TagLib::Tag * __cdecl TagLib::FileRef::tag(void)const " (__imp_?tag@FileRef@TagLib@@QEBAPEAVTag@2@XZ) referenced in function main
debug\testTag2.exe:-1: error: LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals
```

but when i run application in Release mode,the above error are just some Warning and application run with no problem, why this is happening?
thank you.

Comment: Looks like you provided *only* the Release directory for the linker, so only the Release libraries are available to it: `LIBS+= -LF:\project\TAGLIB\taglib\taglib\Release -ltag`

Comment: You need to build both Release and Debug mode libraries if you want to use Release and Debug mode applications. The runtime for Release and Debug is incompatible with each other.

Comment: @squareskittles no change happend when i added Debug directory for zlib and taglib in LIBS,i have this issue with mvsc2019,in other compiler like msvc15,msvc17 i have no output,they return the same error as msvc2019 debug mode.

Comment: @drescherjm thank you for information, i added Debug directory in LIBS but still have the same problem